# How Big/Low would an artificial satellite have be to change the pull of the tides?

Tags: gravity

I learned that passing airplanes pull the tides in a similar style to the moon, but are too small to make a drastic change. How big would an artificial satellite have to be to make a measureable change? After all, it *is* closer to the Earth.

Comment: I assume you have an *artificial* satellite in mind, correct?  I was a little confused by your question at first.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes. Sorry about that, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Re, "...too small to make a drastic change..." How about, too small to make a _measurable_ change?

Comment: @SolomonSlow done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tidal effects are due to the difference in the gravitational acceleration from another object at two different points on Earth.  If $P$ is the point directly below the object and $R$ is its antipode, then the magnitude of this difference would be
$$
\Delta a = Gm \left( \frac{1}{h^2} - \frac{1}{(2R + h)^2} \right)
$$
where $m$ is the mass of the object in question, $R$ is the radius of the Earth, and $h$ is the altitude of the object's orbit above the surface.

For the Moon, this works out to be about $\Delta a \approx 1.1 \, \mu\text{m/s}^2$.  We can then look at the effect of a satellite in low Earth orbit ($h \approx 400$ km) and solve for the mass required to give this same $\Delta a$.  The result is that you'd need a satellite of mass $2.6 \times 10^{15}$ kg to get the same difference in acceleration over the scale of the Earth.  This is 10 million times smaller than the Moon but is still stupidly large;  it's on the order of a good-sized comet or some of the smaller natural satellites we know of.  Or, if you prefer, it's over 100 million times larger than [the total mass launched into orbit to date.](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/88/what-is-the-total-mass-sent-into-orbit-over-all-history)